# There is other option to connect spring boot to db2?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, db2, spring-jdbc

I'm working with Spring boot, and I need to use a db2 database connection, currently is configured to work with maven and properties, but first I need to create the jks file, and testing part doesn't works because this file is not there.

this is my connection property
jdbc:db2://examplecon:80207/basejl:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=folder/file.jks;

How can I connect spring boot with db2 after that spring finish to set all?

Comment: Do you need any spring relational tools for file creation?

Comment: I don't think so, currently files are created manually in other method (before Spring starts)

Comment: So you need to generate the same file before testing?

Comment: Yep, I need to create the same files after testing part finish

Answer (score 1):

You can start generating the file before the context is been started:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    generateFile("folder/file.jks");
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }

  private static void generateFile(String s) {
    // TODO: generate file.jks here
  }

}
```

In this case you can use the usual way of db connection that is provided by spring.

Like this example:
https://www.sourcecodeexamples.net/2021/08/spring-boot-db2-connection-example.html

For testing purpose, you can use Test Configuration with Event Listener. It will run before Context will start:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
class TestConfigurationExampleAppTests {

  @EventListener(ApplicationStartingEvent.class)
  public void generateFile() {
    // TODO: generate file.jks here
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the way that I'm building jks files, but inside of Junit5 test, files are not created, and the db2 connection tries to find this files, and then all of test fail

Comment: For unit testing you do not need any real db connection. I've added a case for integration tests.

Comment: If I try to run test cases, and jks files are not there (because are created when the app runs) fail because this line 
jdbc:db2://examplecon:80207/basejl:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=folder/file.jks;


in my application.properties is present, test are trying to find the files but these are not still created

Comment: You can use test.properties for testing, where you will not refer to this file or generate this file like I added to my answer

Comment: didn't work, because jks file is needed as part of the configuration of "springsource" here  -> sslTrustStoreLocation=folder/file.jks, so tests can not start

Comment: This method will start before springsource starts. Check that this method is really invoked: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationStartingEvent.html